# Retrieve Values from Array with class

Tags: swift

I have a custom class defined as such:

```
public class Location {
    var name = String()
    var address = String()
    var place = String()    
}
```

I'm then populating an Array using that class as follows:

```
    var chosenLocation = [Location]()
    var locationResult = Location()

//Code to parse data here//

        for result in results! {

            locationResult.name = result["name"] as String
            locationResult.address = "Bogus Address"
            locationResult.place = result["place"] as String
            chosenLocation.append(locationResult)
        }
```

This all seems to be working fine, but when I try to get the individual "name" value in cellForRowAtIndexPath I just get the last record over and over. I guess I just don't understand how to reference each entry since it's a class wrapped in an array. The code I believe is in question, and which is returning the same row over and over is:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"cell")

        var locationAnswer = Location()
        locationAnswer = chosenLocation[indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = locationAnswer.name            
        return cell
    }
```

I believe it's getting appended to chosenLocation correctly, but since I don't know how to "unwrap" it , a println only shows me that I have the correct number of values and not what's in them.

Thanks a bunch for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the bug is that just a single Location object is created and updated, so it contains the data from the very last update

Move the creation to be within the for loop...

```
// var locationResult = Location() <- Remove this

for result in results! {
    var locationResult = Location() // <- Add it here
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jawwad provided a solution to the problem.

Note that your code doesn't work because the item you are adding to the array is an instance of a reference type (class), so you are instantiating once, initializing at each iteration, then adding to the array - but what's added is just a copy of the reference to the instance, and not the instance itself.

Your code would work just fine if you turn the `Location` class into a struct. Being value types, structs are passed by value and not by reference, so the action of passing the same instance to the `append` method results in a copy of that instance to be created and passed.